# How can I update an ArrayList that belongs to a specific user in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on a small project in firebase where I'm trying to have it so that you a user can onto an existing list of strings. Right now every time someone tries to do this, the user object gets reloaded into the database. If you anyone could help me out here that would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void saveSelectionInDatabase(){
    String text = selectionSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    User userOne = new User();
    userOne.userAddItem(text);
    listofStuff = userOne.places;
    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userOne);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Information Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onClickAdd(View view){
    saveSelectionInDatabase();
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listofStuff);
    genericListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your database structure?

Comment: done and added the structure

Comment: im not understanding your requirement, can you be more specific ?

Comment: Basically I want it so that users are able to add and remove types of places they want to go to. I'm trying to store these types of places within an arraylist each user has.

Comment: You mentioned that "the user object gets reloaded into the database" in a way that implies it is not the desired behavior. Just to clarify, is the issue you're experiencing that the child `DatabaseReference` (which has a path of the current Firebase user UID) does not get set to the new value of `userOne`? Or that it does not include the `places`? If the issue is the latter, do you know for sure that your `userAddItem` method is actually setting the `places` property correctly?

Comment: The current problem is that I am not able to append to previously selected places. By "reloaded", I mean the userOne object is an entirely new object that discards previous selections made.

Comment: I'm assuming that is because you are making a new object. Perhaps rather than saying `User userOne = new User()`, you could get the value of the data snapshot of the child at the path with the Firebase UID, and assign that to `userOne` instead. Then, all the pre-existing data would be there.